# Where can i find good UI designing tutorials for Android

Tags: android-layout

I need some good links which will teach more about User Interface for Android. UI is very important as users prefer good Ui apps. I already have knowledge about the basic UI designing in Android. But i want to make it more attractive. Help me guys. Thnx in advance

Answer (score 6):

I'd say if you know the mechanics of making a UI in Android, what you need is a guid to making a good UI in general. Here are some recommended books for that.

Robin Williams' [The Non-Designers Design Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321534042) (great for learning about layout, grouping, typography).

Steve Krug's [Don't Make Me Think](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321344758) Yes I know it mentions the web specifically, but a lot of the concepts apply to any UI

Jennifer Tidwell's [Designing Interfaces](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449379702) Good collection of common UI Patterns (also see the companion website.

Robert Reimann's [About Face](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470084111) if you don't pick up any other book on UI design, get this one.